# How to recover symbols from utf-8

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, utf-8, ascii

Encoding in Python 2.7 is very hard to understand. Can someone explain to me how get these string's symbols?

Here is my unicode string:

```
my_str = u'MFADCINEMve000301119 FACTURE EFAD CIN\u2019troD+000000035165 EUR FACTURE EFAD CIN\u2019trop\xe9MA SAS 2019/10198'
```

And I want to convert it to get "\u2019" and "\xe9".

I already try to `my_str.encode('utf-8')` but this gives me that:

```
'MFADCINEMve000301119 FACTURE EFAD CIN\xe2\x80\x99troD+000000035165 EUR FACTURE EFAD CIN\xe2\x80\x99trop\xc3\xa9MA SAS 2019/10198'
```

with other encoded symbols. I don't understand that, I juste want to replace them into **'** and **é** symbols...

UPDATE:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

Here is my code:

```
day = datetime.now().day
        month = datetime.now().strftime("%b")
        year = datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
        filename = "ventes{0}{1}{2}.csv".format(day, month, year)

        with io.open(filename, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file_data:
            csvwriter = csv.writer(file_data, delimiter=',', quotechar="", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

            for line in res:
                csvwriter.writerow([x for x in line])  # Occurs error bellow

        file_data.seek(0)

        out = base64.encodestring(file_data.read())
```

That occurs this error (not necessarily explicit):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 546, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 583, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 319, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/service/model.py", line 118, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 316, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 812, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/http.py", line 412, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 953, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 941, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 268, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/api.py", line 399, in old_api
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons_eggs/adquat_export_CEGID/models/export_cegid.py", line 31, in validate
    move_ids = self._context.get('active_ids', [])
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 136: ordinal not in range(128)
```

What's wrong with this code? Please help !

Comment: In your update, the bytes were written correctly, but you have the file open using the wrong encoding (most likely WIndows CP1252 based on my experience/testing). Re-open it using UTF-8 encoding and you should see the correct characters.

Comment: In your second update, that error is not from the code shown. The cab module in Python 2 doesn’t support Unicode strings. Python 3 had better support and Python 2 is no longer supported. If you won’t switch, there is an example at the bottom of the cab module documentation on how to handle Unicode, or get the 3rd party unicodecsv module.

Comment: Mmh okay.. I'll investigate, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Python 2 by default displays string representations (`repr()`) as ASCII-only.  Any character outside the ASCII range (0-127) is displayed as an escape code (`\xnn` or `\unnnn`).  The character is only displayed correctly visually if you `print` the character, and then only if the terminal encoding and font support the character.

For example:

```
>>> s = u'\xe9'
>>> s             # This is a representation of the string useful for debugging.
u'\xe9'
>>> len(s)        # It is still only length 1.
1
>>> print(s)      # It displays correctly when printed.
é
```

My terminal's encoding doesn't support all Unicode characters by default, so you're other example doesn't `print`.  The debug representation does, however:

```
>>> s = u'\u2019'
>>> s
u'\u2019'
>>> len(s)
1
>>> print(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\encodings\cp437.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_map)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>
```

If you write a Unicode string to a file, you have to encode it.  Open a file with the encoding you want and write the Unicode string.  It's best to use UTF-8 as the encoding, as it supports all Unicode characters.   Use `io.open`.  It is compatible with Python 3 (which you should switch to ASAP) and supports the `encoding` parameter.

```
import io

my_str = u'MFADCINEMve000301119 FACTURE EFAD CIN\u2019troD+000000035165 EUR FACTURE EFAD CIN\u2019trop\xe9MA SAS 2019/10198'
with io.open('out.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(my_str)
```

Note you have to view the file in an editor that supports UTF-8.  For example, on my terminal with its default `cp437` encoding it looks like:

```
C:\>type out.txt
MFADCINEMve000301119 FACTURE EFAD CINΓÇÖtroD+000000035165 EUR FACTURE EFAD CINΓÇÖtrop├⌐MA SAS 2019/10198
```

But if I change the encoding to cp65001 (UTF-8):

```
C:\>chcp 65001
Active code page: 65001

C:\>type out.txt
MFADCINEMve000301119 FACTURE EFAD CIN’troD+000000035165 EUR FACTURE EFAD CIN’tropéMA SAS 2019/10198
```

More reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/))
- [Pragmatic Unicode](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Comment: Hello and thank you so much for spend all this time to reply me. I understand better unicode but... that not works for me... sorry but can you see my updated answer with my code and tell me what's wrong with me? Thank you for all!!

Answer (score -1):

You just need to do `print(my_str.encode('utf-8'))`

This will give you the output:

> MFADCINEMve000301119 FACTURE EFAD CIN’troD+000000035165 EUR FACTURE EFAD CIN’tropéMA SAS 2019/10198

Comment: Ooh okay. Thanks for reply but it works only in print method? My purpose is to write this line in a CSV file and see my updated question what that print in my file... Have any solution? Thank you so much!!

Comment: `encode()` just converts the unicode escape (`\u2019`) into the equivalent bytes (`\xe2...`). `print` is able to interpret the bytes to display the correct character - writing to a file will do the same thing so you'll have the characters written as you expect in the file.